# Playing the multiple Audio files in different Views using single audio player instance in iphone,

Tags: iphone

I am new to audio playing, I am having one issue regarding Audio playing .The issue is Playing the multiple audio files , and controlling the current playing audio file from other Views.

My Requirement is. In my app i am having 4 audio files in different Views. Once the audio play button is clicked in some View, The audio playing has to be started  and pause and stop and slider buttons has to be displayed , Even i navigated to the next view the audio has to be continued (I should be able to control the currently playing audio), If i pressed the navigated view's audio, The previous audio has to be stopped, Navigated page audio has to be played. After completion of Navigated page Audio, the resumed audio of Previous page has to be played.

```
As of my knowledge, I have take single audio instance in AppDelegate. I am referring  that Audioplayer instance in all view's , Where ever i need. It is not working.(some times giving error , some times unable to stop the Previous Audio playing).
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try looking at "CocosDenshion" framework http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/cocosdenshion:faq
it should make things a bit easier if u are new to using sounds on iOS. i use it even if not using the cocos2d framework and just building a normal app.

Answer (score 0):

if i am not wrong you have defined the audioplayer in appdelegate, right?

and which class are you using for this , avplayer , avaudioplayer or mpplayer ?

and by the way , if we come to answer of mine,

i have used avplayer and avaudioplayer for this kind of business and it worked without problem , have you checked that in everyview you initialize you appdelegate instance? if not please check this and

also in your plist file , you should state that app will play audio in background to get the support for that.

hope this answer will help! :)

Comment: I have used AVAudioPlayer but it is not working. Can I use Singleton AVAudioPlayer for this Kind of Business.